# Passing DOM elements to another page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

So, I understand this is an odd question. I have 2 pages, one that somebody fills out w/ a bunch of inputs. The next page would be a "print to pdf" type deal w/ Coldfusion. However, I want to send all the info to the next page and not lose what the person entering data has put in. Is there a way with jQuery (or some other option in CF that I haven't seen) to potentially grab the `$('body')` and pass it to sub in on the next page so it keeps the `<input>` values? I don't want to do a form submit, as there are a bunch of calculations that also take place based off those inputs that are shown, using javascript, and `<cfdocument>` has trouble with javascript after the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would serialize all the form input values using [jQuery's serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/), and store it in the localStorage. In the next page, just read the localStorage and parse your data back to an object using JSON.parse.

Page 1 :

```
localStorage.formData = $("form").serializeArray()
```

Page 2 :

```
var formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.formData)
```

...aaaand you'll get all your data in an object on page 2.

Comment: Awesome! So then what would I do to pass the non-form, calculated data? Does `.seralizeArray` work on non-form data? In the documentation it appears to only be for forms.

Comment: Any string can be stored in the LocalStorage. Grab any values from your DOM with jQuery, store them in the LS and retrieve them on another page. SerializeArray is just a very convenient shorthand to grab and JSONize all the data in a form.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Jeremy. Learn something every day. However, `cfdocument` more or less prevents me from being able to render javascript, unless it is preset as something i can read as a CF variable, so #form.id1#, #form.id2#, etc.

Comment: If my answer is correct to you, please validate it :) But sorry, I don't have a clue about Coldfusion. Never used it...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the element data to local storage worked, but the way I actually did it was writing the `$('body').html()` to a string, passing that using `$.ajax()` to a cfc file, where I wrote a text file to the CF temp directory using `<cffile>`, then re-rendered that text into HTML/CFML on the PDF page using `<cfinclude>`. Hope this helps someone if they need it!

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the data for use on another page in CFML. I do this with Railo, but Adobe CF has a similar function. Any data I want to use on the next page goes in to an array of structs. I haven't tried cacheput('formdata', form), but it seems like it would work.

```
Page 1
// Empty cache storage
cacheClear();
// call the function to cache data
cachePut('cData', data);

Page 2
// get items from the cache
data = cacheGet('cData');
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I have never used cacheput/cacheget, but it seems like it would be viable. The form data is actually incidental, the reality is that I wanted to re-render the entire `<body>` of the page on the next, preserving form data and calculations based off that data.